# Getting an error when trying to write a promise: Promise resolver object is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong when I'm writing this promise? I want the first function in calculate to execute and then setState of the component after the calculations are complete.

```
var calculate = new Promise({

            function(resolve, reject) {
                var newSubtotal = 0;
                var newTotal = 0;

                this.props.cart.map((product)=>{

                    newSubtotal += product.price;
                    newTotal += product.price;
                    newTotal *= 1.10;

                });
                resolve(newSubtotal, newTotal);
            }
        });

        calculate.then(() => {
            this.setState({
              subtotal: newSubtotal,
              total: newTotal
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are passing object but function is expected

it should be something like this

```
var calculate = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
// some stuff
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
 calculate.then(() => {
        this.setState({
          subtotal: newSubtotal,
          total: newTotal
        });
    });
```

has no access to newSubtotal, newTotal.

How about?

```
 calculate.then((newSubtotal, newTotal) => {
        this.setState({
          subtotal: newSubtotal,
          total: newTotal
        });
    });
```

Also, add: `reject(someFailCase);`